# Does my page have to have the HTML5 doctype to access sessionStorage

Tags: caching, html, html4

Our dev shop continues to support IE6 etc.  I'm wanting to [use session storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304284/can-html5-sessionstorage-be-written-to-disk) to make an app-cache but wondering how much work it would be...

Is it possible to use an HTML4 doc type in an HTML5-compatible browser and still access the sessionStorage, or do I have to browser sniff and return different pages (perhaps just with doctype alteration) to get it to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you can. Browsers *don't care* about doctypes. HTML 4 strict or HTML 5 won't make a difference, just make sure your page is in Standards Mode, not [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

Personally, I don't see a reason not to use the HTML5 doctype, as you would be using HTML5, and, unlike any of the others, you can *remember* it!

Of course, session storage as defined in HTML5 won't work in IE6—but it is up to you to decide what kind of fallback you'll provide.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629/any-reason-not-to-start-using-the-html-5-doctype

Answer (score 0):

Good question... theoretically the answer is no, but practically it's vendor dependent.
My solution would be to have the server check the user-agent and dynamically tag the page accordingly to what you find out when testing cross-browser implementation. Unfortunately this is one of those things you can't do dynamically on the client (change doc type) as you would with Javascript implementation fixes.

Comment: No, the answer is not vendor-dependent. It’s not even theoretically no. (There’s nothing in the sessionStorage spec suggesting that support be disabled based on doctype.) The answer: sessionStorage doesn’t depend on the doctype in any way.